# How to send a message from signalr selfhost server to javascript client

Tags: javascript, c#

I am successfully send a message from javascript client to signalr self host server..

**Now i want send a message from signalr selffhost server to javascript client..**

I am using Visualstudio 2012 C# console application as server and C# web html page as client..

Thank you...

Comment: It's send the same way you would do in a web host environment. There're a lot of articles on this topic

Comment: Can u Please send the reference..